# Why is backpatching needed during intermediate code generation?

Tags: compilers

In compiler design, control-flow statements are translated to sequences of three-address-code (3AC) instructions a lot of which are jump statements. A 3AC instruction of the jumping type  could be an unconditional jump in the form of a goto statement with a target label as its argument, such as

> goto L1

or it may be a conditional jump in the form of an if statement, as in

> if a < b goto L1

Now when the compiler generates a 3AC jump instruction, the target label is available to it in the form of an inherited attribute ( which I assume is a pointer to an object/structure and so we could think of it as a pointer to a variable ).

Now, the labels passed to say, an if-else statement as inherited attributes would also be then attached to certain target instructions **after the if-else construct that used those labels has been translated**.

Suppose, a label L1 has been used a lot of times before in constructs that have now been  translated. Now suppose that label has to be attached to say a target assignment statement (the next instruction to be emitted) whose index is in the array of instructions is 137 (because there are 137 3AC instructions already stored in the quadruples array). Then at this point of time the variable L1 would get the value 137 and so all the earlier uses of L1 would also now get the value of L1 (because the variable pointed to by them now gets a value).

And so in this way we have translated control-flow statements in one pass and there is no need for backpatching to reduce the number of passes further.

I don’t understand why what I just wrote wouldn’t work and without backpatching two passes would be required to attach labels to their correct instructions.

Comment: Your text is a bit hard to read. Can you break it into shorter paragraphs?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  Ok I have shortened it. I just wanted to be as clear and detailed as possible and so I wrote too much.

Comment: What if L1 appears after the *goto L1* instruction?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Once you reach L1, its value gets set correctly and since L1 is a “variable”, that change would automatically be reflected back in goto L1.

Comment: Consider the following code: "goto L1 ... L1:". What do you output for "goto L1"?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus You just output the symbolic label L1 which is actually a variable storing the actual address.

Comment: You are describing backpatching. You output a placeholder, and later on, when you figure out the address of L1, you fill in the placeholder.

Comment: What does it mean to output the symbolic label? This would mean that you really output some pointer (which has to be marked as such), and later on, you will go over the entire generated output, and replace all pointers to the value they point at. This is just an implementation of backpatching.

Comment: I suggest studying a language like C. Perhaps your background is only in modern programming languages such as python.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus We really output some pointers but the value of the pointer is not updated in a subsequent pass but rather when the target instruction for that label is generated. Also I am well versed in C.

Comment: This is exactly backpatching. When you reach L1, you update all previous mentions of L1.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Back patching says you physically replace all the L1’s that have previously occurred with their actual address. However, what I am saying is you just change the value of L1. The L1’s remain L1’s. They are not actually changed.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Btw, I think the reason that you are supposed to replace each occurrence of a label Lx by its actual address (index of array) such as 1001 instead of using symbolic names like Lx because apparently direct addressing is more efficient than indirect addressing. But I am not sure and this is just what I think.

Comment: So you're suggesting to use an additional memory address just to store the address of the label? That does seem pretty inefficient, especially when considering execution. Memory access is something that you really want to avoid. It makes a lot of sense to spend a bit more time compiling in order to significantly decrease the running time.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ok I got this insight because I asked this question somewhere else and there a guy told me that the reason behind backpatching is that it is preferred to use direct addressing. And now that I go through my text again it says the same thing, but I couldn’t understand it earlier on because it says it in a hard to understand way (and also it just says a single line about it). But now I have another question.

Comment: If you have a different question, please ask it separately. Meanwhile I will summarize the discussion in a short answer.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ok btw I asked another question earlier today where you commented. Could you please help me with that one?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert on compilation, so I cannot answer all question in that area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you encounter a jump instruction "goto L1" before encountering the label L1 itself. The solution you propose (as far as I understand) is to reserve a location M1 in memory at which L1 will be stored, and to translate "goto L1" into an instruction of the form "jump to the address stored at address M1". Later on, upon reaching L1, you update location M1 with the address of L1.

This is a form of "runtime backpatching", in which the processor itself is doing the backpatching when running the code. Accessing memory tends to be slow, and so it is much better to hardcode addresses, shifting the effort from runtime to compile time. This is where backpatching comes in. When encountering "goto L1", the compiler will note that the address is missing, and will fill it in later, when the address of L1 is known.